# How can I reset a Windows USB device using python?

Tags: python, windows, usb, reset

I have a number of USB 3 cameras that sometimes lose connection, and need to be reset to continue. At the moment I am unplugging the USB cables to reset them, but this is long and time consuming. How can I reset the devices using a python script?

I am not really sure where to start, I have tried using the pywinusb and managed to get a script to print some names of HID devices but it didnt find the cameras, and am not sure what to use to cause the reset.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#
"""
Show all HID devices information
"""
import sys
import pywinusb.hid as hid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if sys.version_info < (3,):
        import codecs
        output = codecs.getwriter('mbcs')(sys.stdout)
    else:
        # python3, you have to deal with encodings, try redirecting to any file
        output = sys.stdout
    try:
        hid.core.show_hids(output = output)
    except UnicodeEncodeError:
        print("\nError: Can't manage encodings on terminal, try to run the script on PyScripter or IDLE")
```

I want the script to loop through each of the connected cameras and then reset them one by one. Is this possible? Any direction or help would be greatly appreciated, especially if there is an easy fix to this. Thanks

Comment: Hello, first google shot : https://gist.github.com/18516329677/5e143eb8ecf80d21b2fcb36baec0c9f4

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me. Unfortunately fcntl is specifically for managing Unix operating systems. I am looking into wi32api but it seems like a lot to learn. Thanks

Comment: FYI there are USB HUB with power switches if it will be too hard to implement via app, something like this : https://allegro.pl/oferta/hub-usb-3-0-aktywny-rozdzielacz-4-porty-zasilacz-6706514409?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=_ELKTRK_PLA_Komputery&ev_adgr=Urz%C4%85dzenia+sieciowe&gclid=CjwKCAjwtO7qBRBQEiwAl5WC25i-XrZILl7Ewuwb19dHMcIayuy5gUUf4srIsQFQI21MbJJV2ubHzBoCjE4QAvD_BwE

Comment: See this superuser post for how to automatically install DevCon.exe: https://superuser.com/a/1751153/378683  You then programmatically talk to DevCon.exe over the console to do what you want.